# AccessViolationException - Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqlxml, target-platform

Installed Os - Windows 10 64 bit

Installed sqlxml_x64.msi and using Microsoft.Data.Sql.Xml in my application

Created console application - Framework 4.5.2

Here is my logic to get data from SQL database.

```
SqlXmlCommand cmd = new SqlXmlCommand("My SQL connection string");
cmd.CommandText = "/Tbl_Name[@Column_Name='SomeValue']";
cmd.CommandType = SqlXmlCommandType.XPath;
cmd.SchemaPath = "My xsd file path";
string strResult;
    try
    {
        strm = cmd.ExecuteStream();
        strm.Position = 0;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strm))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
```

When executing my application in x64 (Platform target) getting "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt" in cmd.ExecuteStream() line. Incase if i run the application in Any CPU option with enabled preferred 32 bit option, application working fine.

I am not sure why its not working in Platform target as x64 and why its working in x86 and Any CPU with preferred 32-bit enabled option. Because i am installing Sqlxmlx64.msi and referring 64 bit Microsoft.Data.Sql.Xml.dll in my 64 bit console application.

Comment: interesting. could you please provide full exception details including full exception call stack?

Comment: System.AccessViolationException : Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.CopyToManaged(IntPtr source, Object destination, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.Common.ManagedSeqStreamWrapper.Write(Int32 buf, Int32 len)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.ISQLXMLCommandManagedInterface.ExecuteToOutputStream()
at Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.SqlXmlCommand.innerExecute(Stream strm)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.SqlXmlCommand.ExecuteStream()

Comment: looks like a bug in the library. let's look it up

Comment: you're not the only one. here are the (so far abysmal) related threads: https://forums.asp.net/t/2094516.aspx?attempted+to+read+or+write+protected+memory+this+is+often+an+indication+that+other+memory+is+corrupt+, https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/6e4fee4e-e38c-4ae8-b91b-172c9dffc661/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-this-is-often-an-indication-that-other-memory-is?forum=Offtopic